# Why is Magento Sales Order View blank?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

We have recently moved a client site from a temporary domain to their live one. In doing so, the 1st screen of the Sales Orders (`/sales_order/view/order_id/x`) is now coming up blank.

When we click on the option to create an invoice or any other element of the order process the order data comes up.

We have seen one resolution which was to reinstall `Interface_Adminhtml_Default` via Magento Connect; however that did not resolve our issue.

Any suggestions on what we can do to resolve the matter?

Looking deeper into this I am seeing the following within the code:

```html
<li>
  <a href="#" id="sales_order_view_tabs_order_info" name="order_info" title="Order Information" class="tab-item-link ">
    <span><span class="changed" title="The information in this tab has been changed."></span><span class="error" title="This tab contains invalid data. Please solve the problem  before saving."></span>Information</span>
  </a>
  <div id="sales_order_view_tabs_order_info_content" style="display:none;"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: If you want an answer from stack overflow, you're going to need to include the error message that the written to your exception and/or PHP error log when you attempt to load the sales order page.

Comment: That's the biggest problem - there is no error being shown in the logs or in the file itself. Looking at the source, it just shows an empty div where the content should have been.

Comment: OK, so it's not "blank" — HTML is still being rendered.  Including the source of the document will increase the chances someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Have you also checked PHP logs ?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue with php 5.4 and when we rolled back to php 5.3 everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alan is right. But let me throw you a bone...

There are scripts on the internet that will let you delete all your test orders, test customers, test invoices, test deliveries and test refunds (yep, that is British terminology). Now you might want to clear out all the test transactions and see if it works thereafter. It is just an idea, goes nowhere towards understanding the problem but might give you the Sales Orders view back and allow you to get your client's site live.

Another tool you may be interested in is the database repair tool for Magento. It will flag up anything wrong with your database.

As it sounds like you have checked the admin code is all okay cleaning up the db might be the way to go given no log errors being readily available.